# How to perform the mutation of dropdowns status in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, graphql

I want to make a change of state when an item is selected in my dropdown but a bug occurs that does not change without clicking again.

I know there are related questions but my code is a particular case.

[image: Sample image]

The same thing happens to me as this image with my two dropdown.

[image: Sample image]

I change "Mes" but it does not work until you return and select another value. There I just changed to "month 4".

[image: Sample image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import format from 'date-fns/format';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './style.css';

import {
  ButtonDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
} from 'reactstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import TituloSmall, { types } from '../TituloSmall';

const query0 = gql`
  query postsDiaComoHoy($dia: Int!, $mes: Int!) {
    posts(first: 2, dia: $dia, mes: $mes, categoria: 28) {
      rows {
        id
        fecha_dia_hoy
        imagen_intro
        titulo
        introtext
        autor
        fulltext
        fulltext2
        imagen_banner
        categoria {
          id
        }
        tags {
          id
          titulo
        }
      }
      count
    }
  }
`;

const renderTagItem = item => {
  const { id, titulo } = item;
  return (
    <Link key={id} to={`/tags/${id}/`}>
      <div className="tag">{titulo}</div>
    </Link>
  );
};

const removeTagHtml = valor => valor.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g, '');
const removerTwitter = valor => valor.replace(/- @\w+/g, '');

let updated = 0;

let dates = format(Date(), 'D');
let month = format(Date(), 'M');
export class DayScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.props,
      currentIndex: 0,
      sortItem1: month,
      sortItem2: dates,
      cantidadMeses: [
        'Enero',
        'Febrero',
        'Marzo',
        'Abril',
        'Mayo',
        'Junio',
        'Julio',
        'Agosto',
        'Septiembre',
        'Octubre',
        'Noviembre',
        'Diciembre',
      ],
      diasMes: [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29,
        30,
        31,
      ],
    };
  }

  state = {
    items: [],
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.getArticles();
    updated = 0;
  }



  getArticles = async () => {
    const changeArticles = `
    {
      posts(first: 3, dia: ${this.state.sortItem2}, mes: ${month}) {
        rows {
          id
          fecha_dia_hoy
          imagen_intro
          titulo
          introtext
          autor
          views
          fulltext
          fulltext2
          imagen_banner
            categoria {
            id
          }
          tags{
            id
            titulo
          }
          }
        count
      }
    }
    `;

    if (updated) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:4000/graphql/?query=${changeArticles}`,
        ) .then(response => {
          this.setState(() => ({
            items: response.data.data.posts.rows,
          }));

          let { data } = this.props;
          const { items } = this.state;

          data.posts.rows = items;

          return response;
        });

        // Log the response so we can look at it in the console

        // Set the data to the state



      } catch (error) {
        // If there's an error, set the error to the state
        // this.setState(() => ({ error }));
        console.log(error);
        // console.log(this.state.error);
      }
    }
  };

  selectIndex = direction => {
    const { currentIndex } = this.state;
    const {
      data: {
        posts: { count },
      },
    } = this.props;

    let nexIndex = currentIndex + direction;
    nexIndex = nexIndex < 0 ? count - 1 : nexIndex;
    nexIndex = nexIndex >= count ? 0 : nexIndex;
    this.setState({ currentIndex: nexIndex });
  };

  monthSelected() {
    const { sortItem1, sortItem2, dropdownOpen1 } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      dropdownOpen1: !dropdownOpen1, 
    });
    if (dropdownOpen1) {
      month = sortItem1;
      dates = sortItem2;
      updated = 1;
    }
  }

  dateSelected() {
    const { sortItem1, sortItem2, dropdownOpen2 } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      dropdownOpen2: !dropdownOpen2,
    });
    if (dropdownOpen2) {
      month = sortItem1;
      dates = sortItem2;
      updated = 1;
    }
  }


  onDiasChanged=(e)=>{
     this.setState({sortItem2:[...e.currentTarget.innerHTML]});
   }

   onMesChanged=(e)=>{
    this.setState({sortItem1:[...e.currentTarget.innerHTML]});
  }



  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    if (data.loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    if (data.error) {
      return <div>{data.error.message}</div>;
    }

    if (data.posts.rows.length <= 0) {
      return <div>Nada que mostrar...</div>;
    }
    const {
      data: {
        posts: { rows },
      },
    } = this.props;

    this.items = this.props.data.posts.rows;
    const {
      currentIndex,
      sortItem1,
      cantidadMeses,
      sortItem2,
      dropdownOpen1,
      dropdownOpen2,
      diasMes,
    } = this.state;

    const item = rows[currentIndex] ? rows[currentIndex] : rows[0];

    const html = item.fulltext + item.fulltext2;
    const image = `${process.env.REACT_APP_IMG_BASE}${item.imagen_intro ||
      item.imagen_banner}`;

    data.variables.mes = sortItem1;
    data.variables.dia = sortItem2;
    return (
      <div className="containerDiaComoHoyNoticia">
        <div className="box">
          <span />
          <span />
          <div className="mesTexto">{cantidadMeses[sortItem1 - 1]}</div>
          <div className="diaTexto">{sortItem2}</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className="textoContainer">
            <div className="tituloDiaComoHoyNoticia">
              {'BUSCA QUE OCURRIÓ EL DÍA QUE TU QUIERAS EN EL FÚTBOL'}
            </div>
            <div className="separatorLinea" />
            <div className="listaMesDia">
              <span className="circuloMesDia">1</span>
              <span>Mes</span>
              <ButtonDropdown
                isOpen={dropdownOpen1}
                toggle={() => {
                  this.monthSelected();
                }}>
                <DropdownToggle color="white" caret>
                  {sortItem1}
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu>
                  {cantidadMeses.map((items, i) => (
                    <DropdownItem
                      dropDownValue="Mes"
                      dropDownValue="Mes" onClick={this.onMesChanged}>
                      {i + 1}
                    </DropdownItem>
                  ))}
                </DropdownMenu>
              </ButtonDropdown>
              <span className="circuloMesDia">2</span>
              <span>Dia</span>

              <ButtonDropdown
                isOpen={dropdownOpen2}
                toggle={() => {
                  this.dateSelected();
                }}>
                <DropdownToggle caret>{sortItem2}</DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu>
                  {diasMes.map(i => (
                    <DropdownItem
                      dropDownValue="Mes" onClick={this.onDiasChanged}>
                      {i}
                    </DropdownItem>
                  ))}
                </DropdownMenu>
              </ButtonDropdown>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {rows.map(itemArticulo => (
          <div className="listaNoticiasContenido">
            <img
              alt={itemArticulo.titulo}
              src={process.env.REACT_APP_IMG_BASE + itemArticulo.imagen_intro}
              className="listaNoticiasImagen"
            />
            <div className="rectanguloIconoPlay" />
            <div className="contenidoArticulo">
              <div className="tituloArticulo"><a href="#" onClick = {this.state.currentIndex = 1}>{itemArticulo.titulo}</a></div>
              <div className="descripcionArticulo">
                {removeTagHtml(itemArticulo.introtext)}
              </div>
              <div className="escritor">
                <div className="nombreAutor">
                  <div>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="user-circle" />
                    <span className="autorArticulo">
                      {removerTwitter(itemArticulo.autor) || 'Sin autor'}
                    </span>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="eye" />
                    <span className="vistasTotalesArticulos">
                      {itemArticulo.views}
                    </span>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="calendar" />
                    <span className="cantidadArticulosEscritos">
                      {itemArticulo.fecha_dia_hoy}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="separadorArticulos" />
          </div>
        ))}
        <h2 className="tituloDescripcion">{item.titulo}</h2>
        <div className="titlesContainer">
          <TituloSmall
            iconName="user-circle"
            label={item.autor || 'Sin autor'}
          />
          <TituloSmall
            iconName="calendar"
            label={format(item.fecha_dia_hoy, 'DD/MM/YYYY')}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="imageIntro">
          <img className="imageDescription" src={image} alt={item.titulo} />
          <div className="esquinaFigura">
            <div className="boxWhite">
              <span />
              <span />
              <div className="mesTextoBoxWhite">
                {cantidadMeses[sortItem1 - 1]}
              </div>
              <div className="diaTextoBoxWhite">{sortItem2}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <article dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
        <TituloSmall iconName="tags" label="Tags" type={types.BIG} />
        {item.tags.map(itemsTags => renderTagItem(itemsTags))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

DayScreen.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    currentSortItem: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    error: PropTypes.shape({ message: PropTypes.string }),
  }).isRequired,
};

DayScreen.defaultProps = {};

const queryOptions = {
  options: () => ({
    variables: {
      dia: dates,
      mes: month,
    },
  }),
};

export default graphql(query0, queryOptions)(DayScreen);
```

I want the change of state to be made without pressing double click and the delay that I showed in the image occurs.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have directly mutated the `state` and not setting the state using `setState` method so your `render` method will not be called at the time of selection and because of it, you will not getting the change immediately once your render method will be call you will get those changes. so your dropdown implementation should be like.

```
  onMessChanged=(e)=>{
     this.setState({sortItem2:e.currentTarget.innerHTML});
    }

  <DropdownMenu>
                  {diasMes.map(i => (
                    <DropdownItem
                      dropDownValue="Mes"
                      onClick={this.onMessChanged}>
                      {i}
                    </DropdownItem>
                  ))}
                </DropdownMenu>
```

As here you are using the `reactstrap` so it might be possible that your event target may be different so you have to use `currentTarget`

the `currentTarget` refers to the element that the event listener directly attached to while the `target` still refers to the specific element where we clicked.

Comment: I've put it as you mentioned, but it still presents the same problem.  I put the function above render and on the OnClick the this..onMessChanged but it does not work

Comment: I'm debugging and I just realized that in Axios' request, he's keeping the previous id. For example:                                                               
```getArticles = async () => {
    const changeArticles = `
    {
      posts (first: 3, day: $ {date}, month: $ {month}) {```

** dates ** equals 13 and ** month ** equals 2. I must pass the selected day but it is not sent, how could I do it?

Comment: @Mangux: posts(first: 3, dia: ${this.state.sortItem2}, mes: ${month})

Comment: I put it that way and just by clicking, it sends me the following message: TypeError: Can not read property 'fulltext' of undefined

The strange thing is that the dropdown is not displayed with the values, simply the default and when I press click, the error appears

Comment: I already solved it, that is to say, the problem of the undefined no longer appears but it still does not change state when I change the item and I have to click again. I have updated the code as it is now, can you review it please?

Answer (score -1):

First error I see is that you can not set the state directly as `this.state.sortItem = e.target.innerHTML`Instead you have to use `this.setState({ sortItem: e.targetinnerHTML })`

Y por favor, intenta no usar Spanglish xD es una mala práctica.

Comment: You mean it would be something like that?

 ```onClick = {e => {
                        this.stateState ({sortItem1: e.target.innerHTML});
                      }}>
                      {i + 1}```

Comment: Yes. And I would also wrap it in a function for better readability

Comment: I give error: TypeError: _this4.stateState is not a function

Comment: Ready, but do not do anything now when I click